# PowerShell multiple email recipients (attachment) from csv / empty cell issue

Tags: powershell, csv, email, automation, exchange-server

I recently started to work on PS script for email automation.
Manage to put something together where I have CSV file from where PowerShell is extracting data (multiple recipients, attachment, etc).
The problem is, when some of the cells are empty, script won`t work.
There is one [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559486/how-to-skip-empty-cells-in-a-csv-when-using-powershell-to-import-email-addresses), but I am just not sure how to implement solution on my case:

```
$importFile     = "Users.csv"

$users = import-csv $importFile | select *
foreach($user in $users)
{
    $Name           = $user.'Name'
    $to             = $user.'To'
    $to2        = $user.'To2'
    $Attachment    = $user.'Attachment'
    $Attachment2   = $user.'Attachment2'    

    $write = "Emailing account " + $to + " ..."
    Write-Host $write

    $body = [string]::join([environment]::newline, (Get-Content -path $emailFile))

    $body = $body.Replace('[Name]', $Name)

    $mail = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage 
    $mail.From = $emailFrom 
    $mail.To.Add($to)
    $mail.To.Add($to2)
    $mail.Subject = $emailSubject
    $mail.IsBodyHtml = $true
    $mail.Body = $body
    $mail.Attachments.Add($Attachment)
    $mail.Attachments.Add($Attachment2)     

    $smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
    $smtp.Host = $smtpServerHost
    $smtp.Port = $smtpServerPort
    $smtp.EnableSsl = $smtpServerSsl
    $smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = $false
    $smtp.Credentials = $credentials
    $smtp.Send($mail)
```

[This is how looks CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lz3lT.jpg)

Any suggestion is more than welcome :)

Comment: "*One of the most frequent categories of bad questions I see on StackOverflow is: "I wrote this code and it doesn’t work. (code dump) "* - https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ . In what way does it "not work", and which bit of your script does that point to as the problem area?

Comment: Avoid the use of System.Net.Mail.MailMessage : Powershell has the native command Send-Mailmessage (this should cut down your code with 10-15 lines). Can you also clarify what you mean with "the script won't work" and explain which cells are empty in your input file?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler and @bluuf, thank you for inputs. I have added CSV file for better understandings of the problem.
I have managed to add `Where-Object` and provide more details at @gvee reply. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing **IF** function resolved the case. For example if `($to2 -ne '')` is checking if *$to2* cell is empty. If no, then `$mail.To.Add($to2)`. The same situation for $Attachment. Here is the code:

```
$mail = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage 
$mail.From = $emailFrom 
$mail.To.Add($to)
    if ($to2  -ne '') {
        $mail.To.Add($to2)
        }
$mail.Subject = $emailSubject
$mail.IsBodyHtml = $true
$mail.Body = $body
$mail.Attachments.Add($Attachment)
    if ($Attachment2  -ne '') {
        $mail.Attachments.Add($Attachment2)
        }
```

Comment: Can you explain why this fixed the problem?

Comment: For example `if ($to2  -ne '')` is checking if _$to2_ cell is empty. If no, then `$mail.To.Add($to2)` ; if cell is empty, it`s simply skips it. The same situation for _$Attachment_

Comment: That's great, please update your answer so that people in the future can find it more easily. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `Where-Object` to filter out rows.

```
$users = Import-Csv $importFile |
Where-Object {$_.Name -ne ""} |
Select-Object *
```

For what it is worth: if the whole "row" is blank you can shortcut this to simply be

```
...
Where-Object {$_} |
...
```

Comment: `$users = Import-Csv $importFile |
Where-Object {$_.Name -ne "" -and $_.To -ne "" -and $_.Attachment -ne "" -and $_.Attachment2 -ne ""} |
Select-Object *` - skips to send first email in a row

Comment: `$users = Import-Csv $importFile |
Where-Object {$_.Name -ne "" -or $_.To -ne "" -or $_.Attachment -ne "" -or $_.Attachment2 -ne ""} |
Select-Object *` - returns error:

Comment: `Cannot convert argument "item", with value: "", for "Add" to type "System.Net.Mail.Attachment": "Cannot convert value "" to type "System.Net.Mail.Attachment". Error: "The parameter 
'fileN...`